# Independent integrable random variables with 0 expectation so that $\overline{S}_n$ does not converge to 0 in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

> Give an example of independent integrable random variables $X_n$ such that $E[X_n] = 0$ for all n, but $\overline{S}_n = (\sum_{i=0}^n X_i)/n$ does not converge to 0 in probability.

As far as I know, $E[X_n] = 0$ is essentially the same as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty X_n(t)dt = 0$ when the $X_n$'s use the real numbers as their domain, so this question is asking for a sequence of functions which are 0 almost everywhere, but whose sum, divided by n, is not 0 almost everywhere. It seems that I need a sequence of partial sums that go to infinity "faster" than $1/n$ goes to 0, but anything I can think of that might do that seems to be made up of non-integrable functions (functions for which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty X_n(t)dt$ diverge), much less functions that are 0 almost everywhere.

The other idea I had was to perhaps have $X_1$ be $x^2$ (or some other "big enough" function) on the rationals, 0 elsewhere, and each successive $X_i$ be that same function on the rationals shifted by some tiny irrational number, 0 elsewhere, but this doesn't seem like it can work, since the resulting sum would still only be nonzero on a countable union of countable sets, which should itself then be countable.

I would really appreciate just a hint on how to get started with finding the right kind of sequence of functions.

Comment: $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(t)\,dt$ is not correct. For example, take the random variable $X \equiv 1$, then you're saying that $E[1] = \infty$. If $X$ takes values in $\Bbb{R}$ and has CDF $F_X$, then you can say $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t \, dF_X(t)$.

Comment: This is what's always confused me about what E[X] actually means. What does "dF_X(t)" mean in terms of actual computation? I mean, I know that it means we're integrating with respect to F_X, but I'm not sure what that means if I actually know what F_X is and want to calculate the integral.

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable defined on the probability space $(\Omega, P)$ then $E[X] = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega)\,dP(\omega)$. This looks more like the formula you want; however, this is integral is with respect to the measure $P$, which is often less convenient than using the previous formula I gave. As for the "Riemann-Stieltjes" or "Lebesgue-Stieltjes" integral $\int ()\, dF_X$, that is probably worth a different question on MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you ask, this is a hint:

Define $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n} = (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k$.

Define $X_n$ take values $-a_n$ and $a_n$ with equal probability, i.e. $\frac{1}{2}$. All $X_n$'s are independent.

This idea is that $X_n$ take a value so large that it ignores what happened before. And the value is so large that even divided by $n$ doesn't eliminate its influence.

Answer (score 1):

$${}{}{}{}X_n=\pm3^n{}{}{}{}$$